# PrintWriter does not send my string (TCP/IP)

Tags: java, tcp, ip, printwriter

I am making a java applet that has basic chat functionality (you can send/recieve messages). I have made a separate thread to handle the connection on the client version, and the server also makes a thread for every connected client.

in the run() method of the client i have a while loop to read any messages recieved:

```
while (state == ConnectionState.CONNECTED) {
   out.println("Hello Server");
   out.flush();
   String input = in.readLine();
   System.out.println(input);
   if(input == null){
      connectionClosedFromOtherSide();
   }
   else {
      received(input);
      System.out.println(String.format("Recieved something: %s", input));
   }
}
```

Here out is my PrintWriter and in my BufferedReader. For debugging purposes I put the 'hello server' here. This code works fine, but the problem is the sendtext() method:

```
synchronized private void sendText(String tosend) {
   if(out != null && state == ConnectionState.CONNECTED){
      out.print(tosend);
      out.flush();
      System.out.println(String.format("sending %s to server", tosend));
   }
}
```

For some reason, if i call this method, it isn't recieved on the server side. (however the console does show that it is sent)

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: Can you change `out.print()` to `out.println()`? You are sending some data without newline while the other side expects full line.

Comment: Can you show more code like this class where you have defined sendText()

Comment: what is the out an istance of, PrintWriter?  please include the declaration and how you create the instance

Comment: Vikrams comment did the trick: i feel so stupid for not noticing this. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: You shouldn't use PrintWriter or PrintStream over the network. They swallow exceptions you need to know about. In this case you should use BufferedWriter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client side, each

```
String input = in.readLine(); // read until newline
```

should be, on server side, balanced by

```
out.println( tosend ); // print the newline expected by the client
```

`out.flush()` don't send a newline.

Comment: Yes, i had to change out.print(tosend); to out.println(tosend);. thank you for the help!